# How to get sound through HDMI with AMD APU and on-board HDMI

Tags: sound, ati, hdmi

I have just built a NAS/HTPC with the following components:

Motherboard: ASUS F2A85-M LE A85X S-FM2 M-ATX

CPU: AMD A-SERIES X2 A4-5300 3.4GHZ SOCKET FM2

And now Im having problems getting the audio to play through the HDMI cable.

I have not installed any proprietary drivers since everything seemed to work right away. Im using xubuntu because I'm having problems finding anything with Unity. The system seems to recognize the HDMI audio and I can select it in the audio settings. I see the green bar moving when im playing sound but no sound seems to reach my TV. Here are some screenshots of the settings and a pastebin from the aplay -L command:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/699329/sound2.png to sound5.png

(there are pictures up to sound5.png but I cant post that many hyperlinks

http://pastebin.com/Z2WQcyAb

I also found a setting in bios where you could chose SPDIF or HDMI for digital audio and I have chosen HDMI. I have tried choosing different settings in the audio control panel but while none seem to actually crash or stop it doesnt seem as if they output audio either.

I would much appreciate any help I can get since this is the last piece left untill I can use the machine properly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the proprietary drivers from AMD are required if you want to enable HDMI audio through your graphics card. I recently set up a new system with an AMD APU and a small HDTV as the monitor, and installing fglrx got the audio working right away. I don't know of a way of enabling it without that driver.